# asp.net EF code first model for PBX managment

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model, ef-code-first

I want to make the simple application to use with my PBX. I want to manage the providers and Lines tat connected to my PBX. The main objects are `Provider` and `Line`. Every provider has some lines connected to it. Lines can be added or deleted enabled or disabled and reserved. I want to keep the status of lines and history of actions in one table. Does this right solution or I need to create another table for history?

```
public class Line
{
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public Provider Provider { get;set;}
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string OutNumber { get; set; }
    public string InNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Begin_datetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime End_datetime { get; set; }
    public Human TechGuy { get; set; }
    public Human Manager { get; set; }
}


public class Provider
{
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OurSideData { get; set; }
    public string TheirSideData { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Begin_datetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime End_datetime { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best solution for the code first model creating in the logic like that? Maybe I need to add some additional fields?

Answer (score 0):

You need another table for history.  Something like:

```
        public class Line
        {
            public int LineId { get; set; }
            public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }
            public string Login { get; set; }
            public string Pass { get; set; }
            public string Domain { get; set; }
            public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
            public string Project { get; set; }
            public string OutNumber { get; set; }
            public string InNumber { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime Begin_datetime { get; set; }
            public DateTime End_datetime { get; set; }
            public Human TechGuy { get; set; }
            public Human Manager { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<LineStatusHistory> ChangeHistory { get; } = new HashSet<LineStatusHistory>();
        }

        public class LineStatusHistory
        {
            [Key( )]
            public int LineId { get; set; }
            [Key()]
            public int LineStatusHistoryId { get; set; }
            public virtual Line Line { get; set; }
            public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }
            public string Change { get; set; }
        }


        public class Provider
        {
            public int ProviderId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string OurSideData { get; set; }
            public string TheirSideData { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime Begin_datetime { get; set; }
            public DateTime End_datetime { get; set; }
            public Currency Currency { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Line> Lines { get; } = new HashSet<Line>();
        }
```